# How to specify the file encoding for pyarrow.csv.write_csv?

Tags: python, csv, pyarrow, apache-arrow

When reading a CSV file with pyarrow, you can specify the encoding with a `pyarrow.csv.ReadOptions` constructor.

However, I find no equivalent on `pyarrow.csv.write_csv`:

- The `pyarrow.csv.WriteOptions` does not have an `encoding` argument
- If you pass a file-like object instead of a file name, it must be opened in binary mode, so the encoding cannot be specified when instantiating the file object

So how can I specify the encoding when writing to a CSV file?

Comment: It appears from the documentation that `pyarrow` only wants to write a .csv using UTF-8 encoding. What you could do is pass a file-like object that decodes what is written to it by `pyarrow` from UTF-8 on the fly and re-encodes it to whatever you need. However, do you actually need an encoding different from UTF-8?

Comment: In this specific case, I want the output to be encoded with `utf-8-sig` to ensure that it opens correctly in Excel. I'll try as you suggested.

Comment: In that case, just opening a binary file and writing the BOM to it and then allowing `pyarrow` to write the rest would do? After all, other than the BOM at the start, it'll just be good old UTF-8 - no need to decode and re-encode.

Comment: Ah yes of course! Just `f.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)` does it. Thanks!